# Using powerlaw module in python

Tags: python, power-law

I'm trying to use powerlaw module for a very simple case and it's not working properly. I read the documentation but didn't understand quite well. Using the code below, I'm getting `8.36310071704202`, instead of `0.5`, the exponent of my `lambda` function

```
import powerlaw
func_powerlaw = lambda x, exp: (x**exp)
xdata = np.linspace(1.0, 10, num_points)
num_points=10
exp=0.5
y=func_powerlaw(xdata,exp)
plt.plot(xdata,y,'bo')
results = powerlaw.Fit(y)
print results.power_law.alpha()
```

Comment: This module isn't for fitting an exponential function to your x-data. It is for fitting a powerlaw _distribution_ to a given data sample.

Comment: why, do you need a named `lambda` when you can simply do `y = xdata ** exp`?